# How could an animal run fast using blade-like feet that sink into spongy ground?

Tags: creature-design, physics, xenobiology, fauna

In my fictional planet, forests grow not on soil, but on vast spongy mats of fungi. Traditional Earth-like feet would struggle to get grip on the squishy ground, so most megafauna taxa have feet like blades that cut into the fungus.

[image]

*A very rough drawing of a classic fauna example from this world*

On this world, however, I want to have cursorial predators, like cheetahs, with high speed and agility. The thing is, I'm not sure if the "feet sinking into ground" idea would  impair their speed.

So, what I'm asking is: **How would such a (quadrupedal) predator run, and what anatomical/morphological adaptations would it have to do so?**

I suppose you'll need more clarification on the "How would it run" part, so this is what I mean:

On the diagram below (Note: that is not what the creature actually looks like) I've labelled the respective feet 1, 2, 3 and 4.

[image]

When a leopard runs, it puts one foot forward at a time, so its running style would be like this, going by the diagram:

1 - 2 - 3 - 4

A running cheetah brings its two forelegs forward, then its hind legs, like this:

1,2 - 3,4

Which style would be more suited to running with blade-like feet in springy, spongy ground?

Then, the second part of the question was "What anatomical/morphological adaptations would it have?". By this, I basically mean stuff like the shapes of the blade, overall build, spikes on the blades for grip, etc.

So, if I was to sum up the ideal, but not necessarily required, qualities, it should be able to:

- Run at over 100 km/h
- Jump 10 metres horizontally
- Jump 4 metres vertically
- Accelerate at 9 m/s

Answering with A) Which running style, and B) Morphological adaptations, what is the closest the creature could get to those abilities?

**EDIT:** Just had another idea. What about a second, smaller blade, perpendicular to the big one, that helps pull the creature back out of the sponge? Here's another very rough drawing to help you visualize it:

[image]

Comment: How elastic is the surface?  If the answer is something other than than "not it all", it might be in organisms' best interest not to dig into it, but to spring off it.  There'd be trade-offs in agility since they can't maneuver in the air, but they'd conserve a lot of energy.  You might also consider making the blades' direction orthogonal, or at least diagonal, to the direction of motion

Comment: I feel like you might be trying to work backwards from blade feet, rather than working forward from sponge-earth... if that is the case try the question the other direction "what kind of terrain would logically support blade feet"

Comment: Cheetah top speed is around 100 km/h on pretty ideal terrain. You're asking how to get cheetah speed on terrain that is far from ideal. I wonder if your creature really needs to get to that speed, or if it just needs to be the fastest thing on that terrain?

Comment: Check out what Klann linkage is.

Comment: Seems like trying to running in water to me...

Comment: This is probably the cutest apex predator I've ever seen

Comment: @SydneySleeper I know right. Actually, the organism drawn isn't the apex predator I spoke of, but, *sigh*, one can dream...

Comment: @Gregor "Life finds a way."

Comment: It occurs to me that the only way this makes sense is if the surface is spongy from the top but has more horizontal tensile strength, so the "blade" allows the animal to grip into the horizontal strength of the material to push off against.

Comment: The only plausible way to make blade-like feet work is to make the surface of the planet extremely flat, extremely hard, and extremely slippery. Something like a frozen ocean-planet with vast areas covered by ice. Then you could put [speed skating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_skating) cheetahs with blade-like feet on it.

Comment: It won't be able to do those things, just as a mouse won't be able to leap out of a 5 gallon pail half full of water.

Comment: I wouldn't call these feet “blade–like”.  They are spike–like.  Yikes.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin - I'd think a broken, extremely slippery hard surface might make more sense for the feet OP is picturing - one might move on flat land with suckers or by sliding, but to go up and down slopes or navigate (slippery) broken ground, one would need to dig in somehow, and the narrow tips would make it easier to dig into small crevices or brace the feet between chunks of rock/ice/the-hard-slippery-stuff in heaps.

Comment: 1) Maybe this would be easier if you explained why you think blade-like feet make sense for this creature in the first place?  Our own planet has lots of fast moving creatures - pretty much none of them have blade feet, however.  As others have noted, blade feet would be particularly poorly-suited for terrain that they might sink deeply into.Is the planet very windy, requiring creatures to anchor themselves?  

2) What stops the whole leg from sinking into the sponge after the knife foot has cut through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gigantic Quad **Inverted Opposable Dewclaws** with a curved elongated spade shape that conforms to the limb during full compression.

A feline's hind legs store an amazing amount of energy when they are compressed during a stride. These dewclaws would do the same thing and help the limb explode from the soft ground, because they are compressed as they enter the hole created by the limb.

[image][image]

You can keep the toes if you want. I just Xed them out for illustrative purposes. This would be such an advantage over those waddling around with webbed feet that this creature would be at the top of the food chain and likely also the fastest land animal on the planet.

---

Kinda like using a lever action post hole digger, backwards. If you stick it in the ground with the jaws closed and then open them, it'll pop back out of the ground. Or at least it would, if the hinge was (inverted) at the tips of the blades. How you're going to convince Nature to build that is on you, but I certainly wouldn't put it past *her*.

Comment: Yo, dawg. I heard you like blades on your feet. So I put some blades on the bladed feet of your bladefoot.

Comment: This would simply not work. For the "dewclaws" to be effective, they'd need to be storing and providing a substantial amount of energy but this would not function. The blades would either not store enough energy to be useful _or_ would simply cut through the "fungi" as they expanded and then need to be dragged out slowing the creature down. Some kind of full umbrella might function but it's going to far inferior to simply having larger webbed feet.

Comment: You want the spurs to operate in the inverse direction, obviously.  They are folded against the spike leg until it enters the sponge.  As it enters, the spurs fold out with friction, slowing the creature and storing potential energy in some spring mechanism.  When the creature retreats one leg, the springs at the bases of the spurs aid in the removal of the spike.  I'd agree with that answer…

Comment: Just leaving the "dewclaws" fully extended at all time so the limb does not sink into the ground will be more effective. Sinking into the ground is time and energy lost from the stride.

Answer (score 52):

> In my fictional planet, forests grow not on soil, but on vast spongy mats of fungi. **Traditional Earth-like feet would struggle to get grip on the squishy ground**,

That's not correct.

Feet adapt to the environment, and squishy ground requires a large surface area.  Consider the duck: webbed feet to provide large surface area to not sink too far, and claw toes to provide grip.

https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/webbed-toes-duck-16472000.jpg
[image]

[image]

> so most megafauna taxa have feet like blades that cut into the fungus.

That's the worst possible design, since it'll quickly chop up the ground and you'll sink even further.

Comment: But would splayed-out snowshoe-like feet be able to reach the speed and acceleration mentioned in the question?

Comment: @SealBoi they might not have to be *duck* feet, just something wide enough to not sink.

Comment: What might be effective is the feet collapsing into a thin cross-section to avoid drag or getting caught on stuff. This would provide to appearance of blade-like feet, which on closer examination would be spreading over the surface instead of sinking in. Bonus if the feet collapse with a quick, strong movement, that could add additional speed (much like a flick of the wrist throws a projectile further and faster)

Comment: @Morgen - Instead a frame challenge [I interpreted](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/112014/799) the question as how it could be an advantage... *the 'feet' collapse with a quick, strong movement adding additional speed* - yes that, in a way.

Comment: @SealBoi have you ever tried to chase a duck around? They can be pretty quick. If the feet are fully part of the animal then it can fold up the feet and make sure the toe doesn't dig in, etc.

Answer (score 23):

You're actually looking to solve this issue in the exact opposite way that would be effective. Bladed feet on a soft mushy surface would result in a "spinning-car-tire effect", as the blades would cut right through the mycelium like butter, .

The trick is actually to look at ways of locomotion that create as little friction as possible, much like the act of sidewinding seen in desert snakes.

If I were you I would research the different types of locomotion used by various Desert Fauna here on earth, (as loose sand is a lot like the mushy fungi you are thinking of) like the sidewinder snake and the frilled lizard.

I would also take a look at the Jesus Christ Lizard (I know, you'll know why they call it that when you see it.) for inspiration.

IMO, the types of predators that would hunt in a Biome covered in soft fungi would most likely be fairly sedentary, and then when prey comes near, use quick bursts of energy to catch said prey if it gets too close. Moving around constantly in an environment like that would require a lot of energy, as you would have to constantly contend with the mushy ground. It would be like trying to run through Jello everywhere you went.

Comment: well, flows of small sand particles aren't quite like a nonflowing compressive mass.

Answer (score 10):

I'm no expert. I just saw this in hot stack questions.

---

That said, I see everyone is disagreeing with the blade idea and I think they're right, but I wanted to offer you another solution/perspective.

When traversing mud in a truck, you might use wide tires and high speed to skim the surface. Or you can choose tall narrow tires to cut through the mud into more solid ground below.

[image: mud truck]

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  This is a good answer, missing only the line drawn between bladed feet and the depth of the spongy ground.  You've made a good point.  Thanks!

Comment: Remind me of https://youtu.be/4oeJjzdlTuI?t=1m17s . Wouldn't work with blades though? :/

Comment: @JBH - I wasn't sure there was a definitive depth to the spongy layer, so like Wilf points out, it may not be feasible.

Answer (score 9):

The problem you are trying to solve is the same problem faced by predators on our world. The ground on most biomes may not be mushy, but many kinds of soil are unforgiving for running creatures that don't have proper gripping.

[Speaking of cheetas](http://www.dccafrica.co.za/cheetah-facts/adaptations-to-speed/):

> They also have **semi-retractable claws which grip the ground**, giving them traction whilst they run.

The animal you drew might have quite the grip, but placing those legs in the ground, and removing them, might take quite a while. A predator with claws that are short, sharp, and in large numbers will also have grip, and will be able to both run and change direction much more easily. Those same claws are also very good for slashing prey dead.

---

Answering the question proper:

A) I don't have the math and biology in me to say which running style is better, but I think the cheetah's will provide more grip per stride. So I'm going with cheetah.

B) Cheetahs might fare very well in this world, and if introduced there as an alien species they might unbalance the local ecosystems. Any further adaptations would probably be physiological rather than anatomical, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

if those points are that big they will not be moving very fast, they will not be able to pull those out at the end of stride without being slowed down significantly. There is such a thing as [too much traction](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1046/j.1420-9101.2000.00166.x) for running creatures.

Second blades make for poor grip, traction claws are triangular with a flat side towards the ground for a reason. Claws that cut make for very poor traction.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be:

- the slow part of the stride would be the digging the claws into the ground. The creature counteracts this by taking longer leaps like a toad, The creature would bury its claw into the mud then pull back on elastic limbs to catapult its self forwards. This is similar to the mantis shrimp’s hammer.
- the claws are flat on the back to prevent them digging into the mud and sharp on the front to allow them to quickly slice out of the mud that has pooled around it since the last claw hit the mud.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but I didn't see any indication of a liquid component to the fungus sponge.

Answer (score 1):

I like the sedentary predator idea that was posted earlier. There are quite a few options. Make it like a huge trapdoor spider, or give it HUGE feet and really good camouflage, and when the prey gets close it leaps and tackles it.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate the bladed feet sideways so they turn into fat paddles that spread weight.

When it wants to cut the surface, it just stands on tiptoe.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well this would fit in to your world, but maybe their legs could be long enough to reach some solid ground and just walk like that. Or, instead of using the ground, they could rely on tree roots for solid footing to get around.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work from your premise that spikefeet are the best way to walk along this fungal sponge.

A cursory computation tells me that the structure of the sponge makes it much more compressive in the downward direction than it is horizontally:  standing on it is like standing on a trampoline or waterbed.
However, if you were to slice out a cube of the fungus, and rotate it so that the former top is now facing to the horizon, you would discover that the cube is firm enough to bounce pogo atop it.

*Caveat:*  I did not model or test any of this.  I seems like it could work, but probably would not.  Maybe it would require tweaking the conditions or method.

[Another answer](/a/112014/27708) suggested use of spurs.  Here is my suggested improvement on that idea:

1. Spikefoot penetrates the top surface of the fungal sponge.
2. Spurs along the spikefoot, tips pointed downward, are pulled outward with the friction of the fungal sponge.
3. Mechanisms at the hinge of each spur store energy.
   Springs operate with a linear i.e. curveless conversion of kinetic energy to potential energy, so you might want a system of hydraulic compression which increases the amount of energy required to unfold the spur exponentially.  However, there is a reason why springs are springy but hydraulic cylinders are not.  Gaseous, maybe?
4. As each spur penetrates transversely to the main spike, the area of the cisverse force downward is spread wider, causing the spike to gradually cease penetrating and begin compressing the fungal sponge.
   Would the spurs simply tear away at the fungus and dig a hole into which the foot would sink?
   Well, for the fungal sponge to be compressive in one axis but not a perpendicular one tells me that its structure is densely packed in the vertical layers but loose in the horizontal layers.  However, for the spike to penetrate vertically, it would need to displace the fungus sideways.  Doing so could only work if the displacement was redirected vertically i.e. up and down — where the sponge is compressive.  For such to happen, and for the fungus to not simply turn into a big mush, would require that the sponge is also very strongly cohesive along the horizontal layers.
   Seems to me that spikes, therefore, would easily penetrate vertically but not horizontally.
5. As the spurs tend to horizontal, their penetration is arrested and the spikefoot halts.  Total penetration is balanced by the heft or weight of the creature, the force exerted horizontally by the spurs, and the pressure of the mechanism at the base of each spur.

Slower gait is achieved by inserting each foot, then withdrawing it.  To spring forward, the foot is forced downward farther with each step.  However, this would be much slower than if the compression of the fungal sponge was used like a trampoline.  Such movement might not be feasible with a sponge that doesn't compress horizontally.

Comment: Keep in mind that this answer attempts to tackle two aspects of the system so as to achieve the arrangement you requested:  how the foot would operate and how the sponge would function.  If you were to give further details on your fungus, or on why you want the foot to be a spike or even if it needn't be, then this answer could be modified to accommodate.  Or, more likely, invalidated … so, now you are stuck with it unless it gets deleted for being erroneous.

Comment: Actually, this project is only in early development, so the properties of the sponge haven't been sorted out yet. How the foot would operate is partially what I'm trying to find out here.

Answer (score 0):

They'd want to be more like ski poles, which actually serve a similar purpose, but on snow:

[image]

It's good to stab the ground for traction, but only up to a point. If you sink in far you are wasting energy. Once you've got traction you want the sinking/stabbing to stop, so you need a flare like the end of a ski pole, that is flat and wide to resist sinking any further.

The stabby part probably wouldn't need to be very long. If the moss is more mushy, you want a multi-pronged or thicker stabby part. A longer stabby part just adds more friction and gets you stuck in the goo.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you don't want blade feet; spongy ground is *springy,* so why not capitalize on that? Instead of blade-footed runners, you'd have springers that use flexible legs, bent backwards at the knee joints, with a more unusual foot arrangement: Picture a clamp, with each side being a curved claw.

These claws are triangular in shape and flat on the underside, and holds a springy orb, like a bouncy ball. When this mass strikes the ground, thanks to Newton's 3rd law (equal and opposite reaction), the creature's claws squeeze the orb, rapidly increasing the pressure put on the ground. As the force brings it up, it continues pressing down by straightening its legs, launching it forwards at high speeds.

This would be equivalent to jumping on a trampoline with miniature trampolines as the soles of your shoes (Yes, I know people don't really jump on trampolines with shoes) and would likely require special adaptations.

Its head may be tipped with a woodpecker-like beak, with a space between the beak and the skull to absorb force, and a special bone-muscle arrangement that would lock its head in place when it looks straight ahead. This would distribute force throughout its spinal column, preventing massive damage in one spot in favor of minor damage throughout the body.

But why would one want this? For one purpose: *Impalement.* Simply put, this creature uses it's powerful legs (and maybe even it's tail) to turn itself into a biological missile, lancing its prey at high speeds. Special fins along the sides could spread out or retract to stabilize and change its trajectory, with the tail now acting as a rudder.

Alternatively, it could have scythe-like forelimbs that start swinging forward as it leaps up, impacting the prey as it lands with the momentum of its jump, or if the orbs it uses to jump can be retracted, then perhaps its claws could lock together into spikes, channeling the force of impact; which will be much more efficient.

Protruding fangs or downward-pointing horns (perhaps even a spiked underbelly?) could have the same effect; when it lands, it would slam into the prey with the full force of its body, impaling it in multiple places.

Other good options (with the leaping legs) are telescoping arms or tentacles on the back, which would have hook-like claws or clamps at the end. This would allow it to do one of two things: 1. grab onto prey and then leap, pulling onto the prey both to ensure accuracy of attack and add momentum to the strike, or 2. to leap up and carry the prey with it before slamming or throwing it down, perhaps even *landing* on it! (Talk about adding insult to injury.....)

A 3rd option would be to leap and then grab onto the trees, allowing it to easily change the angle of its attack (for example: if the prey leaps aside or sidesteps it, it simply pushes off on a tree and swings around, striking it from behind). Essentially, it'd be a biological wrecking ball. With armadillo-like plating and spikes, this could easily be a deadly hunting method in and of itself.

Finally, it could just use the leaping legs to give it a head start. If it had plates of armor (perhaps with added studs for traction) running along its topside, it could roll up like an armadillo and become a living wheel, rolling over the fungi to slam and/or run over the prey. This would have the benefit of conserving momentum, at the cost of reduced visibility....unless it has special "lens", made of clear crystal to protect additional resting on its back? This would allow it to aim just fine when rolled up.

Hope this gives you some good ideas!